# Get User Access Token of Facebook in C# console application

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, console-application

I want to create a C# console application to create a post on my FaceBook account wall.

I tried to search how to get this but all i get is information about get access_token in web application where we can add redirect URL : http://localhost.

I am using below code to get an access_token in Console application.
But i get output from this below code is :

{
    "access_token": "*****|*************",
    "token_type": "bearer"
}
Which App_ID|App_Secret..where user Access_token should be of very big length.

Is this possible to post on facebook account wall using console application??

```
    private const string FacebookApiId = "************";
    private const string FacebookApiSecret = "**************************";

    private const string AuthenticationUrlFormat =
         "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=manage_pages,offline_access,publish_stream";


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string accessToken = GetAccessToken(FacebookApiId, FacebookApiSecret);

        PostMessage(accessToken, "My message");
    }

    static string GetAccessToken(string apiId, string apiSecret)
    {
        string accessToken = string.Empty;
        string url = string.Format(AuthenticationUrlFormat, apiId, apiSecret, "manage_pages,offline_access,publish_stream");

        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();

            NameValueCollection query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(responseString);

            accessToken = query["access_token"];
        }

        if (accessToken.Trim().Length == 0)
            throw new Exception("There is no Access Token");

        return accessToken;
    }
```

Comment: You’re getting the token right? What’s the question?

Comment: I am not getting user access token....i got only the AppID | AppSecret but as a access_token which is not my need.
I want big length encrypted token .